# How can I make this WordPress search optionally consider meta values?

Tags: php, wordpress, search

I'm trying to configure the WordPress search functionality to also consider data stored in a meta field created by the [Advanced Custom Fields](https://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-custom-fields/) plugin.

I am using this code to try and accomplish that:

```
if (!is_admin() && $query->is_search) {

        $query->set('meta_query', array(
            array(
                'key' => 'detailed_product_title',
                'value' => sanitize_text_field($_GET['s']),
                'compare' => 'LIKE'
            )
        ));
}
```

This is yielding for me search results of only posts that contain the search term in the meta field. For example, if I search "white", I receive  only posts with a meta value that contains white within them in my search results.

This leads me to my question:

- How can I optionally search meta values, making my search return posts that hold the search term somewhere within the  meta value, but simply ignoring if meta value otherwise?

**Here is my current code:**

```
function searchProductTitle($query) {
    if (!is_admin() && $query->is_search) {

        $query->set('meta_query', array(
            'relation' => 'OR',
            array(
                'key' => 'detailed_product_title',
                'value' => sanitize_text_field($_GET['s']),
                'compare' => 'LIKE'
            ),
            array(
                'key' => 'detailed_product_title',
                'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS'
            )
        ));

    }
}
add_filter('pre_get_posts', 'searchProductTitle');

function my_posts_where($where) {

    global $wpdb;

    if ( isset( $_GET['s'] ) && !empty( $_GET['s'] ) ) {
        $search = sanitize_text_field($_GET['s']);

        $where .= " OR wp_posts.post_content LIKE '%' . $search . '%'";
    }
    return $where;
}
add_filter('posts_where' , 'my_posts_where');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like:

```
    $query->set('meta_query', array(
        'relation' => 'OR',
        array(
            'key' => 'detailed_product_title',
            'value' => sanitize_text_field($_GET['s']),
            'compare' => 'LIKE'
        ),
        array(
            'key' => 'detailed_product_title',
            'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS'
        )
    ));
```

**UPDATE:**

You won't be able to directly combine the meta_query above with searching the post_content field (using and OR relation).  What you can do is instead of the above, add a [custom query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Queries) like this:

```
add_filter( 'posts_where', 'my_posts_where' );

function my_posts_where( $where ) {
    if ( is_search() ) {

        global $wpdb;
        $search = get_search_query();
        $search = like_escape( $search );


        // include postmeta in search
        $where .= " OR {$wpdb->posts}.ID IN (SELECT {$wpdb->postmeta}.post_id FROM {$wpdb->posts}, {$wpdb->postmeta} WHERE {$wpdb->postmeta}.meta_key = 'detailed_product_title' AND {$wpdb->postmeta}.meta_value LIKE '%$search%' AND {$wpdb->posts}.ID = {$wpdb->postmeta}.post_id)";

    }

    return $where;
}
```

Note that  I haven't tested the above, but that will give you the general idea of what you need to do.

Comment: Great suggestion. However, it gives unwanted results. If a post has "white" in its title, and not in its `detailed_product_title`, it now gets omitted from the results. If a post has white somewhere in it, but its `detailed_product_title` does not exist, then it works as expected. So I need to make it return a post that contains the search term even if it has a `detailed_product_title` that does not.

Comment: I see what you're saying. I'll have to find a way to apply this to my needs involving the post meta. Thanks

Comment: The example code you posted causes all search terms to yield 0 results. Also, it seems to be searching `wp_posts.post_content` - yet I need results based on values within the `post_meta` table. I am currently looking into potential solutions.

Comment: we might need to tweak this a bit, but this is the only way to do it.  you may have misunderstood my answer, but you need to do both.  the code at the top takes care of the post_meta table, and when you add the second bit of code it should add the OR condition where it also searches the post content.

Comment: I have added my current code to my original post. I am using both of your suggestions and this yields 0 results. Have I mistaken something?

Comment: sorry i got it backwards.  try what i have now in the UPDATE section, and get rid of the first section of code.  what we're trying is keeping the existing search query as is, and adding the meta_query to that as an OR condition.

Comment: That did it. Thank you so much for taking the time to help me out here. I really appreciate that.